# Add tooltip to D3 Icicle visual (Observable)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-icicle) **icicle** **visual** on **D3 Observable**. I need to add a **tooltip**, so that it works faster and looks better than native browser version.

I tried this:

```
  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "1px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "10px");

    var mouseover = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 1)
    };

  var mousemove = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .html("hello")
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+90) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  };

  var mouseleave = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 0)
  };
```

And adding the events onto the **rect**:

```
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mousemove", mousemove )
.on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
```

Nothing shows up at all when you hover over the rects of the visual. Can elements be appended to the body in D3 observable?

Comment: do you have any other code or a jsfiddle or your own Observeable notebook? Whats the problem exactly? It shows up but it misplaced or formatted incorrect?

Comment: I've had similar problems but without seeing all your code, its hard to accurately diagnose